# Passing Info Thru URL Not Reaching Server

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I am using a Volley StringRequest to send some basic info to a server where the info is received into a php script and saved into a txt file. Once the user fills in some info and press a button the url is created and passed. The file is being created on the server except the first three fields are coming in null, the remaining 2 (email and zip) are populated. If I log the url to the logcat I can see the url is populated with all fields correctly. I can click on the url in the logcat and the info is sent to the server correctly with all fields populated. I can't figure out why the initial request is not fully received but clicking in logcat is. I don't receive any errors back. The request is

```
String url = Constants.REGISTER_ADDR + "?firstname=" + Registration.this.first.getText().toString() + "&lastname=" + Registration.this.last.getText().toString() + "&userphone=" + Registration.this.phone.getText().toString() + "&email=" + Registration.this.email.getText().toString() + "&zip=" + Registration.this.zip.getText().toString();
                Log.i("SCROLLS ", url);
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                             if (response == null) {
         Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
         Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "ACCOUNT CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                if (error.networkResponse == null) {
                                    if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                                        // Show timeout error message
                                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this,
                                                "Oops. Timeout error!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

A sample url looks like

```
 http://xxxxxxx.com/android/beta.php?firstname=dddd&lastname=aaaaaa&userphone=1112223344&email=aaaa@gmail.com&zip=11111
```

Comment: You should provide some sample code from the PHP code too. Side (un-requested) advice(s): using http and passing that kind of "personal information" using GET it's pretty "bad practice"; you should "urlencode" the values you are sending.

Comment: @Lohmar ASHAR, I will take your advice on the GET. Still confused as to the difference in submitting versus clicking on the url. I know the php is correct as it creates the file and saves the info on the click. But for security I will follow your advice and rework the request.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was "hunting" for some typo or things like that, but if you say that when clicking the link (opening the link directly in the browser) works ... I'd add  some kind of logging on the PHP side ( _log(request.everything)_ ), actually, being a GET request you should have it all in the apache log, you could check these 2 places to see if the params are really missing or there's something else.

Comment: Yes really odd, just clicking the url opens in browser and echos back what I would expect.  Checking the server file shows a complete file. I won't worry about it any more, will change up the way I am sending the info.